# C# Matrix of arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix, jagged-arrays

I'm writing a program in c# that associates an array of 12 elements to a triplet of values. I would like to store my data in a matrix of dimension [n,m,p], but where each element is actually an array. The real world application is saving the output of 12 sensors for each point in a 3D cartesian space.

I tried something like this:

```
int[][,,] foo = new int[12][,,];
```

But this, if I'm right, creates an array of 12 matrices 3x3, while i want a NxMxP matrix of 12 elements arrays.

If I try to specify the matrix dimensions like this:

```
int[][,,] foo = new int[12][N,M,P];
```

I get error [CS0178](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6ax0bze.aspx) (`Invalid rank specifier: expected ',' or ']'`) and [CS1586](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5xt4zz7.aspx) (`Array creation must have array size or array initializer`).

I'm still learning c#, please excuse me for the trivial question, but I can't wrap my head around this. I'm using visual studio 2015.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to create `12` *instances* of `[N, M, P]` matrices organized as an *array* (please, notice that `int[][,,]` is array of matrices, not matrix of arrays):

```
 int[][,,] foo = Enumerable
   .Range(0, 12)
   .Select(_ =>  new int[N, M, P])
   .ToArray();
```

Or

```
 int[][,,] foo = Enumerable
   .Repeat(new int[N, M, P], 12)
   .ToArray();
```

If you prefer loop

```
 // please, notice the different declaration: 
 int[][,,] foo = new int[12];

 for (int i = 0; i < foo.Length; ++i)
   foo[i] = new int[N, M, P];
```

**Edit**: if you want `[N, M, P]` *matrix of arrays* (see comments):

> I'm trying to get NMP instances of 12-elements arrays, addressable by
>   the n,m,p indices

```
  // please, notice the different declaration: matrix of arrays
  int[,,][] foo = new int[N, M, P][];

  for (int i = 0; i < foo.GetLength(0); ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < foo.GetLength(1); ++j)
      for (int k = 0; k < foo.GetLength(2); ++k)
        foo[i, j, k] = new int[12];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not what I'm trying to achieve.
You could say that I'm trying to get N*M*P instances of 12-elements arrays, addressable by the n,m,p indices. I hope this clarify what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Marcomattia Mocellin: you have to change the declaration then, please, see edit.

Answer (score 5):

Try using a 4 dimensional array.

```
int[,,,] foo = new int[N,M,P, 12];
```

Comment: That's one possible solutiom, but given how ugly multi-dimensional arrays in C# are, I wouldn't particularly want to add another dimension to one. Especially if the user needed to be able to pass the 3x3 matrix to some function or another. If that's the case, carving a 3x3 matrix out of your 4x4 matrix could be a real pain.

Comment: that wouldn't be like a list of 15-elements arrays? With this very easy solution, would be possible to call the e.g. 4th element of the first triplet like this: 
   int bar = foo[0,0,0,3]?

Answer (score 1):

```
int[][,,] foo
```

You are creating an array of 3-D arrays (of int). If you want to initialize that array then you would have to do this:

```
int[][,,] foo = new int[12][,,];
```

And then loop through `foo` and for each cell initialize the 3-D array:

```
foo[i] = new int[M,N,P];
```

You can use some LINQ to make it a one-liner (see Dmitry's answer), but it basically amounts to the same thing.

Multi-dimensional arrays in C# are kind of a pain to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will help you (maybe you need only arrays) but you can try to create simple Point3D class. This will improve readibility and, I think, maintanance.

```
public class Point3D
{
    int X { get; set; }
    int Y { get; set; }
    int Z { get; set; }

    public Point3D(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
        this.Z = z;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
Point3D[] arrayOfPoints = new Point3D[12];
arrayOfPoints[0] = new Point3D(0, 2, 4);
```

Comment: Than you, but I don't need to get/set the x,y,z coordinates, i need to associate a 12-elements array to a x,y,z point in space, and I would like to use the x,y,z values as indices (it is possible as they are expressed as ticks, i.e. X=255 means X is 255*tick mm) since in theory it should be reasonable...